# Error Cross Domain calling Json

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain

I'm trying to bring my json file into my HTML but a error Cross Domain is happening:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://guardioesdacidadania.com.br/game_temp/assets/js/caratulas.json?jsoncallback=. The request was redirected to 'http://www.guardioesdacidadania.com.br/game_temp/assets/js/caratulas.json?jsoncallback=', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

I've tried many different solutions but none of them worked.

Here's my js code.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://guardioesdacidadania.com.br/game_temp/assets/js/caratulas.json?jsoncallback=',
   headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
   crossDomain: true,
   success: function () { alert('it works') },
   error: function() {alert('it doesnt work')},
   datatype: 'jsonp'
});
```

Comment: Does the server have it set to allow cross domain?

Comment: That does not appear to be a website that supports JSONP.

Comment: Is the calling page on the same domain? (guardioesdacidadania.com.br)
Have you tried just putting the 'www.' in the url for your ajax call? It's redirecting to that anyway, so at the very least you would have one less factor to deal with.

Comment: yes, its the same domain. How can i allow the server to cross domain? Or how can i know if the server suports jsonp ?

Answer (score 1):

For CORS support to work, the server must be configured to respond with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, sending the header with your request does nothing. You can see a bit of information on how to get this to work by visiting : [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

If you do not have access to the server, then it is not possible to do it via AJAX so you'll need to create some sort of server side proxy to relay the request through.